# Make warnings crash python script

Tags: python-2.7

I'm upgrading pandas within a python project (2.7). It's giving lots of deprecation warnings. That's good. However, it's not telling me WHERE the thing is that it's warning about, and some of the warnings are a bit obscure, like:

```
/Users/brianp/work/cyan/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:6211: FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version.........
```

I'd like it to crash, and give me a stack so I know what line on my code it's complaining about...

Preferably, I'd like to be able to do this with just a command line option to python, but if that's not possible....

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have python error on warnings, run with

```
python script.py -Werror
```

For more information see

https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-w